# USB Fax 56K modem only shows RING on HyperTerminal after executing AT+VCID=1

Tags: at-command, modem, fax

I have a multiple USB 56K fax modem that used to work fine and display caller id after the second RING when executing ATZ followed by AT+VCID=1 with response OK, but no with the same device and same scenario it only shows RING mutiple times without showing the caller phone number. I have no idea why did that happen, any help??

Comment: Have you tried with `AT+CLIP` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with my USRobotics modem, i tried this command AT#CID=2 and after this command it displays the date time and number after the first ring.

But i noticed that for each time you open the port the caller id is disable

I hope this comment helps you.